# CMakeLists.txt | Помогите скомпилировать исходный код c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, clion, cmakelists

Имеются исходные коды, как я понял, на C++
https://github.com/fossephate/JoyCon-Driver

Я хочу собрать "exe-шник" с небольшими изменениями в коде, но в C++ разбираюсь на уровне "1++ = 2". То есть никак.

Проект, похоже был собран автором в visual studio. Я клонировал его в CLion от JetBrains, но вот незадача - требуется какой-то файлик CMakeLists.txt. Файлик-то я создал:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(LIBRARY_FILES "libs")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_UI
        "${LIBRARY_FILES}/*.cpp"
        "${LIBRARY_FILES}/*.h"
        )
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_IMPORT
        "${LIBRARY_FILES}/*.cpp"
        "${LIBRARY_FILES}/*.h"
        )

add_library(hidapi ${SRC_UI} ${SRC_IMPORT})

set(SOURCE_FILES "src/main.cpp")

add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Файлик-то я создал, но после сборки программа не видит библиотеки, вероятно в VisualStudio "зависимости" (подключаемые библиотеки) указывались как-то по другому. Если кто разбирается, помогите пожалуйста, как заполнить этот файлик, чтобы программа запустилась?

Comment: вот точно скажу, что "неэкстрасенсы" сразу уходят отсюда

Comment: Я добавлю скрины \ детали \ еще информацию, какую Вам надо. В main.cpp на 14-й строке идет строка с "#include <hidapi.h>". Обращаясь к интуиции, я полагаю что происходит подключение библиотеки.

Но при компиляции возникает следующая ошибка: hidapi.h: No such file or directory

Из чего я делаю вывод, что "окружение" (назовём его так) не знает где лежит библиотека hidapi.h. Также, раз на гите уже лежат собранные файлы, предполагаю что VisualStudio знала где "брать" библиотеку. Осталось лишь найти "где" это было указано в студии и перенести эту настройку в CLion. 

Но это на словах...

Comment: *.h - это заголовочный файл с обычным C++ кодом внутри. Скачай в инете да подсунь своему компилятору

Comment: @Goldus - а какой компилятор у Вас?

Comment: GLOB_RECURSE - моветон

Comment: @KoVadim - В разделе "Toolchains" указан "VisualStudio", C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools. Какой компилятор скрывается за этими строками - я не знаю.

Comment: @Maggot, а как правильно? В "сорцах" есть папка "libs", там есть некоторые из "помеченных красным" библиотек. Я просто хотел указать папку, где их искать, но действительно не знаю как правильно это делать. То что вы видите - классическая первая строчка гугла.

Comment: @Goldus может и мой поинт не идеален но я перечисляю файлы. да тупо. бонально. но в мейк файл попадет токо то, что я закажу

Comment: @Goldus а с каких пор первая строчка гугла первая инстанция?

Comment: @Maggot, я сильно отстаю от вас в терминологии. Насчёт "первой инстанции" не знаю. Но начать с чего-то надо, это обычно первая строчка гугла. Потом вторая, третья. Потом подумать. Ну, а когда совсем "беда" - привет, stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел то что искал - мне помог простой скрипт на питоне: https://github.com/gns333/Vcxproj2CMake

Преобразует файлы студии (.vcxproj) в файлик CMakeLists.txt.

Честно, до сих пор не понимаю как это работает и мою общую проблему с нехваткой библиотек это не решило, но библиотеки из папки /lib компилятор подтянул, поэтому считаю, что этот ответ имеет право на жизнь.

P.S. Автор не добавил очевидных способов запуска скрипта, как вариант, в конец файлика можно бросить что-то вроде:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Select vcxproj file!')
    parser.add_argument('source_file', help="Link to source file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    source_file = args.source_file
    filename = source_file.split("/")[-1]
    project_dir = source_file.replace(filename, "")
    generate(vcxprojfile=source_file, vcxprojDir=project_dir)
```